# How to find out available key-value pair for CircuiTikZ

Tags: circuitikz, pgfkeys, key-value

I'm using CircuiTikZ and I came across this issue frequently: every time I want to tweak some options using `tikzset`, there is no documentation for the available key-value pairs.

For example, if I want to change the voltage direction, in the documentation, only value (i.e., `RPvoltages`) is provided. However, I prefer to use key-value pair in my code for future reference so I was wondering how can I find the respective key name given value name or the other way around.

Comment: My editor will search for text along pathnames, which I currently have set for the LaTeX source code (cls and sty files).  If you search for the component name you will find a file filled with things like `\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height/.initial=.3}`  OTOH, the manual is doing a much better job now than it used to.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks. A lot of parameters are internal-only, though, for a practical reason: they are not supposed to change and are not taken into account in the `\savedanchor`-`\anchor` mechanism, so they have to be treated only by people that know what it's doing.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... which manual did you read?

Page 187, Currents and Voltages:

[image]

As often happens, `RPvoltages` is a package options, and a style, and `voltage dir` is the key storing it.

Anyway, let me say that it's a bad idea to use a non-global `voltage dir`. This thing is cultural --- if the book uses EF style, all must be in EF style, or the other way around. `old` and `noold` should have been removed, but I do not *ever* make changes that can result in *wrong* circuits...

Anyway, it's quite possible that the documentation is lacking or can be made better. You are welcome to make an enhancement request (even better if a PR!) at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/new/choose!

For example, I'd really like to add a second index with all the keys pointing to where they are described. But it's a lot of work, so either someone steps in, or it is one of my "retirement project" (not so far away, but don't hold your breath).

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. I just have a quick follow-up question, what is the equivalent key-value pair for the `american` option, is it `voltage = american`?

Comment: Yes, see the just after "5.5.3 American style" --- page 199. Thanks!